# Set up SIM7000E via PPP

Tags: ppp

I am trying to set up SIM7000E via ppp. SIM7000E is connected to a beaglebone black via micro USB cable. Beaglebone uses 5.10.168-ti-r71 kernel (Debian). SIM7000E drivers have been installed successfully and also ppp is installed too.

I entered the directory /etc/ppp/peers, copied the file provider and named it gprs. Gprs file looks like this:

```
# example configuration for a dialup connection authenticated with PAP or CHAP
#
# This is the default configuration used by pon(1) and poff(1).
# See the manual page pppd(8) for information on all the options.

# MUST CHANGE: replace myusername@realm with the PPP login name given to
# your by your provider.
# There should be a matching entry with the password in /etc/ppp/pap-secrets
# and/or /etc/ppp/chap-secrets.

user "myusername@realm"

# MUST CHANGE: replace ******** with the phone number of your provider.
# The /etc/chatscripts/pap chat script may be modified to change the
# modem initialization string.

connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/gprs"

# Serial device to which the modem is connected.

/dev/ttyUSB2

# Speed of the serial line.

115200

nocrtscts

debug

nodetach

ipcp-accept-local

ipcp-accept-remote

# Assumes that your IP address is allocated dynamically by the ISP.

noipdefault

# Try to get the name server addresses from the ISP.

usepeerdns

# Use this connection as the default route.

defaultroute

# Makes pppd "dial again" when the connection is lost.

persist

# Do not ask the remote to authenticate.

noauth
```

Then when I try to call gprs by typing: `pppd call gprs` The result is this:

```
Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/gprs finished (pid 1186), status = 0x0

Serial connection established.

using channel 2

Using interface ppp0

Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB2

sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf0cd2f0e> ]

rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x4 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xd0a7832b> ]

sent [LCP ConfNak id=0x4 ]

rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xf0cd2f0e> ]

rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x5 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xd0a7832b> ]

sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x5 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xd0a7832b> ]

sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0xf0cd2f0e]

sent [PAP AuthReq id=0x1 user="myusername@realm" password=]

rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x6 magic=0xd0a7832b]

rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0xd0a7832b f0 cd 2f 0e]

rcvd [PAP AuthAck id=0x1 ""]

PAP authentication succeeded

sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <deflate 15> <deflate(old#) 15> <bsd v1 15>]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 ]

rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x7 80 fd 01 01 00 0f 1a 04 78 00 18 04 78 00 15 03 2f]

Protocol-Reject for 'Compression Control Protocol' (0x80fd) received

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 ]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 ]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 ]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 ]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 ]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 ]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 ]

sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x1 magic=0xf0cd2f0e]

IPCP: timeout sending Config-Requests

IPV6CP: timeout sending Config-Requests

sent [LCP TermReq id=0x2 "No network protocols running"]

sent [LCP TermReq id=0x3 "No network protocols running"]

Connection terminated.

Modem hangup
```

I do not understand where is the problem. Can anyone help with this?

The /etc/chatscripts/gprs contains:

```
# You can use this script unmodified to connect to cellular networks.
# The APN is specified in the peers file as the argument of the -T command
# line option of chat(8).

# For details about the AT commands involved please consult the relevant
# standard: 3GPP TS 27.007 - AT command set for User Equipment (UE).
# (http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/html-info/27007.htm)

ABORT           BUSY
ABORT           VOICE
ABORT           "NO CARRIER"
ABORT           "NO DIALTONE"
ABORT           "NO DIAL TONE"
ABORT           "NO ANSWER"
ABORT           "DELAYED"
ABORT           "ERROR"

# cease if the modem is not attached to the network yet
ABORT           "+CGATT: 0"
""              AT
TIMEOUT         12
OK              ATH
OK              ATE1

# +CPIN provides the SIM card PIN
#OK             "AT+CPIN=1234"
# +CFUN may allow to configure the handset to limit operations to
# GPRS/EDGE/UMTS/etc to save power, but the arguments are not standard
# except for 1 which means "full functionality".
#OK             AT+CFUN=1

OK              AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","\T","",0,0
OK              ATD*99#
TIMEOUT         22
CONNECT         ""
```

I changed the gprs file in /etc/ppp/peers and put this:

`connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/gprs" -T internet.vodafone.gr`

I tried to call gprs again and the result was this

```
    Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/gprs -T internet.vodafone.gr finished (pid 3457), status = 0x0

Serial connection established.

using channel 27

Using interface ppp0

Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB2

sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x7969ae32> <pcomp> <accomp>]

rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x0 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xd16a9755> <pcomp> <accomp>]

sent [LCP ConfNak id=0x0 <auth pap>]

rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0x7969ae32> <pcomp> <accomp>]

rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0xd16a9755> <pcomp> <accomp>]

sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0xd16a9755> <pcomp> <accomp>]

sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0x7969ae32]

sent [PAP AuthReq id=0x1 user="myusername@realm" password=<hidden>]

rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x2 magic=0xd16a9755]

rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0xd16a9755 79 69 ae 32]

rcvd [PAP AuthAck id=0x1 ""]

PAP authentication succeeded

sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <deflate 15> <deflate(old#) 15> <bsd v1 15>]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::7183:7bdb:7541:1ed2>]

rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x3 80 fd 01 01 00 0f 1a 04 78 00 18 04 78 00 15 03 2f]

Protocol-Reject for 'Compression Control Protocol' (0x80fd) received

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::7183:7bdb:7541:1ed2>]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::7183:7bdb:7541:1ed2>]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::7183:7bdb:7541:1ed2>]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::7183:7bdb:7541:1ed2>]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::7183:7bdb:7541:1ed2>]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::7183:7bdb:7541:1ed2>]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::7183:7bdb:7541:1ed2>]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::7183:7bdb:7541:1ed2>]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::7183:7bdb:7541:1ed2>]

sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x1 magic=0x7969ae32]

IPCP: timeout sending Config-Requests

IPV6CP: timeout sending Config-Requests

sent [LCP TermReq id=0x2 "No network protocols running"]

sent [LCP TermReq id=0x3 "No network protocols running"]

Connection terminated.

Modem hangup
```

Then i changed the /etc/chatscripts/gprs file and put the pin number of my sim card, removing the # sign. Called again gprs and the result now was this:

```
Script /usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/gprs -T internet.vodafone.gr finished (pid 3473), status = 0x0

Serial connection established.

using channel 28

Using interface ppp0

Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyUSB2

sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xc95e726d> <pcomp> <accomp>]

rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x4 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth chap MD5> <magic 0xd172abe9> <pcomp> <accomp>]

sent [LCP ConfNak id=0x4 <auth pap>]

rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xc95e726d> <pcomp> <accomp>]

rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x5 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0xd172abe9> <pcomp> <accomp>]

sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x5 <asyncmap 0x0> <auth pap> <magic 0xd172abe9> <pcomp> <accomp>]

sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0xc95e726d]

sent [PAP AuthReq id=0x1 user="myusername@realm" password=<hidden>]

rcvd [LCP DiscReq id=0x6 magic=0xd172abe9]

rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0xd172abe9 c9 5e 72 6d]

rcvd [PAP AuthAck id=0x1 ""]

PAP authentication succeeded

sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <deflate 15> <deflate(old#) 15> <bsd v1 15>]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]

sent [IPV6CP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr fe80::9012:64df:a80b:4d3f>]

rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x7 80 fd 01 01 00 0f 1a 04 78 00 18 04 78 00 15 03 2f]

Protocol-Reject for 'Compression Control Protocol' (0x80fd) received

rcvd [IPCP ConfNak id=0x1 <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]

sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 10.11.12.13> <ms-dns2 10.11.12.14> <ms-wins 10.11.12.13> <ms-wins 10.11.12.14>]

Modem hangup

Connection terminated.
```

In other words I did not receive a "No network protocols running" message.

Answer (score 0):

Your `pppd` sends a request for configuring compression, specifying both two variants of Deflate and the BSD compression:

```
sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <deflate 15> <deflate(old#) 15> <bsd v1 15>]
```

The remote end rejects the compression request completely:

```
rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x7 80 fd 01 01 00 0f 1a 04 78 00 18 04 78 00 15 03 2f]
Protocol-Reject for 'Compression Control Protocol' (0x80fd) received
```

After this, the remote end entirely stops responding. Apparently "compression" is such an alien concept to it that it is unable to continue connection negotiation once it has been mentioned :-/

Try adding the keyword `nodeflate`, `nobsdcomp` or both of them to the end of your `/etc/ppp/peers/gprs`, one keyword per line.

Another possible issue could be IPv6: unless your mobile network provider has documented that IPv6 is definitely supported, it would not surprise me very much to find that the remote end may have some bugs that get triggered if IPv6 is requested. Try adding `noipv6`.

Alternatively, if your mobile network provider offers *IPv6 only* (I've not personally seen that situation, but apparently that might happen in some countries where IPv4 address shortage was more severe), then you might try adding `noip` instead: if IPv6 is the only thing available, then the remote end might be configured to completely reject any connection attempts that request IPv4.

Don't add both `noipv6` and `noip` at the same time, or else the connection will be pretty much useless: just one or the other.

But if the SIM7000E is not registered to the network at all, then that's probably the root cause of your problems right there.

Your `/etc/chatscript/gprs` expects to get the APN name specified for the `chat` command using the `-T` option, but you are not providing that at the moment. For example, if the APN name you should use (check with your provider) is `internet`, change this line in your `/etc/ppp/peers/gprs`:

```
connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/gprs"
```

to this:

```
connect "/usr/sbin/chat -v -f /etc/chatscripts/gprs -T internet"
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but unfortunately it doesn't work. At first i added only the nodeflate and when i called the gprs still showed me that the Protocol for Rejection is rejected only this time it didn't include the <deflate> line. Then i changed again the gprs file and added also nobsdcomp, called gprs and the result was the same. The only difference was that Protocol for compression didn't show at all. It skipped to the next lines. Still shows the "no network protocols running". Thank you for answering though I appreciate it.

Comment: I also checked what's happening with the modem using minicom. The lines were:    AT showed OK, then i entered Sim's pin by writing AT+CPIN=xxxx (pin's number). It showed me that pin is ready but also threw a message saying "Cannot open /dev/ttyUSB2!".    Then when I checked about network registration with AT+CREG? It showed, CREG: 0,0.  Meaning that is not registered...

Comment: Also with: sudo minicom --setup, i went to Serial port setup and changed the lines and wrote this: A - Serial Device: /dev/ttyUSB2.                  F - Hardware Flow Control set to No and also G - Software Flow Control set to No.

Comment: Tried using noipv6 only then called gprs but the problem persisted. Then tried to use only noip and called gprs and still i had the same problem. /etc/chatscripts/gprs contain this